# Is it possible to clone EC2 AMI From AWS Account A to AWS Account B (Account B is not under Org.)

Tags: amazon-web-services

i have AWS in account A with Account ID 123, Then i want to clone AMI from AWS A with ID 123 to AWS account B with ID 456, But AWS Account B is not under Same OU (Not join that Org.)

Answer (score 1):

You can copy/clone AMI to any other account as explained in AWS docs titled [Cross-account copying](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/CopyingAMIs.html#copy-ami-across-accounts).

Comment: But after i clone done, i add permission as private ami to my new aws ID, But when i check in new AWS account it show nothing,

Comment: @Emo This is new issue for which you have to make new question. My answer addresses your original query of "Is it possible to clone EC2 AMI From AWS Account A to AWS Account B".

Comment: I understood now, it might be cause i shared from AWS account A "Hongkong" then i go to check AWS Account B in "Singapore" it is wrong region it may not work, Anyway thanks you brother.